# Unable to trace the screenshots in Playwright with PyTest framework using setup and yield functionality in conftest.py

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, playwright

Below is my conftest.py code to setup and yield the browser. I am trying to trace all the test cases but am getting an empty screenshot using the below code. Can someone please let me know what's wrong with the below code?

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def playwright_browser(request):
    browser_name = request.config.getoption("--browser-type")
    trace_file = request.config.getoption("--trace-file")
    headless = request.config.getoption("--headless")
    slow_mo = request.config.getoption("--slow-mo")
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    if browser_name == "chromium":
        browser_type = playwright.chromium
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        browser_type = playwright.firefox
    elif browser_name == "webkit":
        browser_type = playwright.webkit
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported browser: {browser_name}")

    browser = browser_type.launch(headless=headless, slow_mo=slow_mo)
    context = browser.new_context()
    # context = browser.new_context(record_video_dir="videos/")
    # context.tracing.start(name="trace", screenshots=True, snapshots=True, sources=True)
    context.tracing.start(name="trace", screenshots=True, snapshots=True)
    yield browser
    #   Stop tracing and export it into a zip archive
    context.tracing.stop(path=trace_file)
    context.close()
    browser.close()

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def page(request, playwright_browser):
    base_url = request.config.getoption("--test-env")
    project = request.config.getoption("--project")
    page = playwright_browser.new_page()
    page.set_default_timeout(60000)  # Set default timeout to 30000 ms
    url = get_URL(base_url, project)
    page.goto(url)
    yield page
    page.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential reason for this could be that the screenshots are being taken before the page content has fully loaded. This can happen if the screenshots are being taken immediately after navigating to a page.

To troubleshoot this issue, try adding a delay before taking the screenshot to ensure that the page content has fully loaded. You can use the `page.wait_for_load_state` method to wait for the page to be in a certain state before taking the screenshot.

Here is an example of how you can modify the page fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def page(request, playwright_browser):
    base_url = request.config.getoption("--test-env")
    project = request.config.getoption("--project")
    page = playwright_browser.new_page()
    page.set_default_timeout(60000)  # Set default timeout to 60000 ms
    url = get_URL(base_url, project)
    page.goto(url)

    # Wait for the page to be loaded
    page.wait_for_load_state("load")

    yield page
    page.close()
```

By adding the `page.wait_for_load_state("load")` line before yielding the page, you make sure that the page content has in fact fully loaded before taking the screenshot.